# Using one form to fill in two other forms

Tags: php, jquery, forms, scripting

OK so I have two different types of forms and I want to use one form to submit them both. I am using a auto-responder form for form1 fields= first, last and email. My second form is a contact me form fields= name. email and a body field. I am trying to use both these forms at one shot. I have a form that will post fields to each form (INDEX.PHP) the problem is I am not sure how to set up form one to post fields into form1 and form2 the way I want. I want to use the fields that match from form index.php to both the other forms (form1, form2). so name and email will go to both forms and the body field will go to form2. The main form will post first and last in the name field of form2....also as you can see from form 1 and 2 each form has a some sort of redirect page I need to work around.?
I have main form:

Index.php

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Main Form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Winner Aution Item Request Form</h2>
        <p><span class="error"><FONT><font color="red">* required field.</font></span></p>
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"> 
            First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name" value="<?php echo     $first_name;?>">        
            <FONT><font color="red"> *</font>
            <br>
            Last Name: <input type="text" name="last_name" value="<?php echo $last_name;?>">   <FONT><font color="red"> *</font>
            <br>
            E-mail: <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>">
            <FONT><font color="red"> *</font>
            <br><br><i><b>Copy and paste auction item name below.</b></i><br>
            Product Name: <input type="text" name="product_Name" rows="1" cols="10">
            <?php echo   $product_Name;?><FONT><font color="red"> *</font>
            <input type="Submit" value="Submit" name="submit"></input>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

the above form was found on a website and was pretty close to what I want it to do but not exactly.... 
Form1

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>autoresponder</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
            <table cellspacing="10" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" style="border: 0px solid #000000;">
                <tr><td>
                    <form action="http://newsletter.jeremyahenry.com//s.php" method=GET>
                        <strong><font color="#660000">Your First Name:</font></strong>
                        <input type="text" name="f" style="background-color : #FFFFFF" size=11 maxlength=40><br>
                        <strong><font color="#660000">Your Last name:</font></strong>
                        <input type="text" name="l" style="background-color : #FFFFFF" size=11 maxlength=40><br>

                        <strong><font color="#000066">Email address:</font></strong><br>
                        <input type="text" name="e" style="background-color : #FFFFFF" size=20 maxlength=50>
                        <input type="image" src="http://blog.jeremyahenry.com/mailermanager/images/go-button.gif" name="submit" value="Submit"><br>
                        <input type="hidden" name="r" value="4">
                        <input type="hidden" name="a" value="sub">
                        <input type="hidden" name="ref" value="none">
                        <br>
                        <font color="#003300">HTML: <input type="RADIO" name="h" value="1">Yes  
                        <input type="RADIO" name="h" value="0" checked="checked">No<br>
                        </font>
                    </form>
                </td></tr>
            </table>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Form 2

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>request form</title>
        <style>p{font:10pt arial;}</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="contact_me/process.php" method=post>
            <table align=left border=0 height=300>
                <tr> 
                    <td nowrap> 
                        <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Your name:&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;<input maxlength=25 name=name size=25>
                    </td>
                </tr> 
                <tr> 
                    <td nowrap> 
                        <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Your email:&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;<input name=from size=25 maxlength=25>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan=2>
                        <center>
                        <p align=center>Enter your Auction item Name below:
                        <br>
                        <textarea cols=50 name=message rows=7></textarea>
                        <p align=center>
                        <input type=submit value="Send Message">
                        <input type=reset value=Reset name="reset">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

ass you can see from the code I was going to use sessions. But not to familiar with it even though I have experience with php I am still quite new to it and need help. I want to pars form data to both forms. and the product name to form two. any help on this would be greatly appreciated.. I hope this is clear enough for some one out there to help.....

Ok New code Three forms 1.main form submits information to form1 and form2.
I have set up using a session so I have: **session.php**

```
    <?php
       session_start();
    // store session data
    $_SESSION['af_first_name'] = $af_first_name;
    $_SESSION['af_last_name'] = $af_last_name;
    $_SESSION['af_email'] = $af_email;
    $_SESSION['cf_address'] = $cf_item_name;

     ?>
```

That handles variables.
My new code for **index.php**

```
    <?php
       // including the session file
       require_once("session_start.php")
    ?> 
    <?php
function stripZlashes($string)
{
    //This function is to strip slashes for either array or a String
    if (!is_array($string)) return stripslashes($string);
    $nvar = array();
     foreach ($string as $key => $value)
     $nvar[stripslashes($key)] = stripZlashes($value);
     return $nvar;
     }
     ?>
     </head>
      <body>
     <h2>Winner Aution Item Request Form</h2>
     <p><span class="error"><FONT><font color="red">* required field.</font></span></p>
     <form name="form1">
     First Name: <input type="text" name="$af_first_name" id="af_first_name"    value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['af_first_name'])){echo stripslashes($_SESSION['af_first_name']); unset($_SESSION['af_first_name']);               } ?>" /><br>

      Last Name: <input type="text" name="$af_last_name" id="af_last_name" value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['af_last_name'])){echo stripslashes($_SESSION['af_last_name']); unset($_SESSION['af_last_name']); } ?>" /><br>

     E-Mail: <input type="text" name="$af_email" id="af_email" value="<?php  if(isset($_SESSION['af_email'])){echo stripslashes($_SESSION['af_email']); unset($_SESSION['af_email']); } ?>" /><br>
     </form>
     <form name="form2">Copy and Paste Auction Name Below!<br>
     Product Name <br><input type="text" name="$cf_item_name" id="cf_item_name" value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['cf_item_name'])){echo stripslashes($_SESSION['cf_item_name']); unset($_SESSION['cf_item_name']); } ?>" /><br>
             <input type="Submit" value="Submit" name="submit" onsubmit="form2.submit(); form3.submit();"></input>
```

That form takes input and sets to session. Session.php picks it up and places it in variable form. From here I used a strip for the underscores. and when it goes to form1 and form2 varables pick it up and fill in the form.  Here is my new **form1**

```
   <?php
function stripZlashes($string)
{
    //This function is to strip slashes for either array or a String
    if (!is_array($string)) return stripslashes($string);
    $nvar = array();
     foreach ($string as $key => $value)
     $nvar[stripslashes($key)] = stripZlashes($value);
     return $nvar;
     }
    if(!empty($_SESSION['_mf'])): //Strip all possible back slashes
   stripZlashes($_SESSION['_mf']);
endif;

     // including the session file
     require_once("session_start.php")
      ?>
     <center>
    <table cellspacing="10" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" style="border: 0px solid #000000;">     <tr><td>
    <form action="http://newsletter.jeremyahenry.com//s.php" method=GET>

    <strong><font color="#660000">Your First Name:</font></strong>
    <input type="text" id="$af_first_name" value="<?php echo (!empty($_SESSION['_af']['af_first_name'])?$_SESSION['_af']['af_first_name']:'') ?>" name="f" style="background-color : #FFFFFF" size=11 maxlength=40><br>

     <strong><font color="#660000">Your Last name:</font></strong>
    <input type="text" id="$af_last_name" value="<?php echo (!empty($_SESSION['_af']['af_last_name'])?$_SESSION['_af']['af_last_name']:'') ?>" name="l" style="background-color : #FFFFFF" size=11 maxlength=40><br>

    <strong><font color="#000066">Email address:</font></strong><br>
   <input type="text" id="$af_email" value="<?php echo (!empty($_SESSION['_af']['af_email'])?$_SESSION['_af']['af_email']:'') ?>" name="e" style="background-color : #FFFFFF" size=20 maxlength=50>

   <input type="image" src="http://newsletter.jeremyahenry.com/images/go-button.gif" name="submit" value="Submit"><br>
  <input type="hidden" name="r" value="4">
  <input type="hidden" name="a" value="sub">
  <input type="hidden" name="ref" value="none">
  <br>

  <font color="#003300">HTML: <input type="RADIO" name="h" value="1">Yes  
  <input type="RADIO" name="h" value="0" checked="checked">No<br>
   </font></form>
   </td></tr></table>
   </center>
    <?php
if(!empty($_SESSION['_mf'])):
   unset($_SESSION['_mf']);
endif;
?>
```

**form2:**

```
    <?php
function stripZlashes($string)
{
    //This function is to strip slashes for either array or a String
    if (!is_array($string)) return stripslashes($string);
    $nvar = array();
     foreach ($string as $key => $value)
     $nvar[stripslashes($key)] = stripZlashes($value);
     return $nvar;
     }
     if(!empty($_SESSION['_mf'])): //Strip all possible back slashes
   stripZlashes($_SESSION['_mf']);
endif;

     // including the session file
     require_once("session_start.php")
     ?> 

     <form action="process.php" method=post>
     <table align=left border=0 height=300>
     <tr> 
     <td nowrap> 
     <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Your name:&nbsp;&nbsp;
     &nbsp;&nbsp;<input maxlength=25 name="af first name" id="af_first_name" value="<?php echo (!empty($_SESSION['_af']['af_first_name'])?$_SESSION['_af']['af_first_name']:'') ?>" size=25> />
     </td</tr> 

      <tr> 
     <td nowrap> 
     <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Your email:&nbsp;&nbsp;
      &nbsp;&nbsp;<input name=af email id="af email" value="<?php echo (!empty($_SESSION['_af']['af_email'])?$_SESSION['_af']['af_email']:'') ?>" size=25 maxlength=25> />
     </td></tr>

     <tr>
     <td colspan=2>
     <center>
     <p align=center>Enter your Auction item Name below:
     <br>
     <input name="cf item name" id="cf item name" value="<?php echo (!empty($_SESSION['_cf']['cf_item_name'])?$_SESSION['_cf']['cf_item_name']:'') ?>"  rows="1" />
    <p align=center>
    <input type=submit value="Send Message">
    </td></tr></table>
    </form>
    </center>
```

Ok now i have an issue with it submitting correctly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form name="form1">
    <input type="text" value="" name="somename" onkeyup="form2.somename.value=this.value" />
</form>
<form name="form2">
    <input type="text" value="" name="somename" />
</form>
```

check out the above code. hope this could be helpful. Or if this is not the result which you require. so you can be brief with your requirements in reply.

Comment: I don't understand what this is doing.? can you comment them to help me better understand what i am doing with this code.? also I need values from form one for both back-door forms..Thanks

Comment: the value whatever will be added under form1 will get added into form2's element while you have valid reference to form2.elementname

Comment: can u give a example of form2.elementname

Comment: try executing the above html content. you would come to know. feels like some misunderstandings needs to be cleared. by being brief on question.

Comment: can't be brief on question when it has a complexity like this since i was not able to find a working answer to my design... Had to be more articulate to have the readers to understand what i am trying to do. also executing it didn't do anything . might be cause I need to know what to put for the value of                    "form2.somename.value=this.value"

Comment: ran the code and got this for form 2 and form one never runs.  SendMail Error

    The following errors have occured:

    ERROR: You didn't enter your name.
    ERROR: You didn't enter your email address.
    ERROR: You didn't enter a message.

Comment: also can you tell me where that bit of code will go?

Comment: no i think your on the right track. I just need to know how to post main form variables to form1 and form2 and submit both forms.

Comment: if more then one form has to be submitted on submit of 1 form then you can utilize onsubmit event of main form as `onsubmit="form2.submit(); form3.submit();"`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the usage or need of your implementation: maybe it is like a 3 step registration form?
 It could be done in different ways without complicating it too much.

You could put all three forms in the same page and only showing the right one
according to th data being posted to the same page. It is the old way of doing things.
 With Ajax calls, templates and javascript it could be don simpler but it depends on
your experience.

Comment: I am trying to be able to use one form to submit information to auto-responder sign up and to send an email with a name of a product in it to where when I receive the email from form2 a filter setting that matches body of form two will email a corresponding email to the person filling out the form...

Answer (score 0):

on each element you can mention as per their relevent events, such as
Ex. `onkeyup="form2.elementname.value=this.value"`

Comment: can you be more specific I am still kinda new to php..and don't i need to ref file for form1 and form2 as like a css file.?